# Custom SAPUI5 icons added to the IconPool sometimes don't display on IE

Tags: javascript, java, caching, sapui5, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with displaying custom icons in IE11 (didn't check for older ones, neither Edge). Chrome and Firefox work properly. Pretty often custom icons that are added to the IconPool are not displayed in IE. After hitting refresh in the browser, they appear normally. Is this a known issue and is there a way to fix this?

The way we do this, is:

1. Fonts details are stored in a json that is hardcoded in the page source under a specific variable (I've shortened the output and simplified the names):

```js
    var myFonts = {
        "iconfonts": [{
            "content": "ea0f",
            "key": "iconFont-icon_search"
        }, {
            "content": "e635",
            "key": "iconFont-burger_close"
        }]
    }
```

2. Then the fonts are loaded by a small utility component (single .js file) method:

```js
    addMyFontsToSAPUI5(myFonts);
```

3. Code for the utility component:

```js
        addMyFontsToSAPUI5 = function(data) {
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    console.log("Loading Icon Fonts");
                    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.IconPool");
                    if (data && data.iconfonts) {
                        var iconfonts = data.iconfonts;
                        for (var i = 0; i < iconfonts.length; i++) {
                            var iconfont = iconfonts[i];
                            sap.ui.core.IconPool.addIcon(iconfont.key, "myfonts", "iconfont", iconfont.content);
                        }
                        console.log("Loading Icons Finished");
                        var eventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
                        eventBus.publish("Icons", "IconFontsLoaded");
                    }
                }, 0);
            });
        };
```

4. After the event is raised, components that use these fonts launch the rerender method. Example controller code:

```js
 sap.ui.define(
        ["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"],
        function(Controller) {
            "use strict";
            return Controller.extend("mynamespace.controller.Main", {
                onInit: function() {
                    var eventBus = sap.ui.getCore().getEventBus();
                    eventBus.subscribe("Icons", "IconFontsLoaded", this.onRerender, this);
                },
                onRerender: function() {
                    console.log("Rerender after icons are loaded");
                    this.getView().rerender();
                }
            });
        });
```

5. Finally, the CSS structure:

```css
    /* My ICONFONT */
    
    @font-face {
    
         font-family: 'iconfont';
    
         src:url('/Fonts/iconfont.eot?-d4jyxw&version=2.1.6');
    
         src:url('/Fonts/iconfont.eot?#iefix-d4jyxw&version=2.1.6') format('embedded-opentype'),
    
             url('/Fonts/iconfont.woff?-d4jyxw&version=2.1.6') format('woff'),
    
             url('/Fonts/iconfont.ttf?-d4jyxw&version=2.1.6') format('truetype'),
    
             url('/Fonts/iconfont.svg?-d4jyxw#iconfont&version=2.1.6') format('svg');
    
         font-weight: normal;
    
         font-style: normal;
    
    }
    
    /* My ICONFONT */
    
    .iconFont {
      /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
      font-family: 'iconfont' !important;
      speak: none;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      text-transform: none;
      line-height: 1;
    
      /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }
    
    .iconFont-icon_search:before {
      content: "\ea0f";
    }
    .iconFont-burger_close:before {
      content: "\e635";
    }
```

Every single console.log is launching properly. Somehow firing the rerender method doesn't make the icons reappear. **The CSS output is not a regular .css file - it's an output resource generated by a Java component** (tho you can display this in the browser under a certain url, but it's not a file physically present on the server).

The components which launch the rerender metod are using the AppCacheBuster.

The application/portal as a whole is working on the SAP Enterprise Portal.

I simply can't determine when exactly this issue occurs, because it seems to happen in some pretty random (seemingly) circumstances. The built-in IconPool icons are always displaying properly.

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue in plunkr? Would be nice to have the not working example and try to check things or debug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible to put something based on the SAP Enterprise Portal into plunkr. The problem seems to lie in the lifecycle itself, whereas its distinct occurence in IE adds additional complexity to the problem.

Comment: It is not needed to put the entire portal in plunkr, but may be reasonable to make an isolated example of an issue, which will allow to look at the problem from different angle and allow someone else to help you.

Comment: Is this issue still reproducible with the latest UI5 version that supports IE11? Is this issue still relevant? As you might know already, [UI5 doesn't support IE11 any longer since v1.88](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/74b59efa0eef48988d3b716bd0ecc933).